# NodeJS, Mongoose - Duplicate entries when inserting data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have NodeJS with Mongoose and I'm accessing an API to retrieve data. I have a Schema as follows.

```
var dataSchema = new Schema({
  id:Number,
  name:String
));
```

And I'm using the following code to insert.

```
  var d = Data.find({id:data.id}, function(error, curr_data) {
    if(curr_data.length == 0) { // check to make sure only unique entries are entered
      console.log("      Inserting : " + curr_data.name);
      new Data(data).save();
    }
  });
```

But when I check my Mongo DB, I can still see duplicate entries.

Is there anther way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mongo's built-in [count() method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) to check if the row exists and from that conditionally save the model:

```
Data.count({id: data.id}, function (err, count) {
  if (!count) {
    console.log("Inserting " + curr_data.name);
    new Data(data).save();
  }
  else {
    // Handle err.
    console.log('Already Exists');
  }
});
```

Comment: You can use the exact same thing with `.findOne` too, which is slightly less memorable but does offer you the full returned db row that you can access properties on if it is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to add an id to your schema, Mongoose creates an ObjectId for you.

"Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor. The type assiged is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDBs default behavior. If you don't want an _id added to your schema at all, you may disable it using this option." - From the [Mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id)

If you do want to specify your own id you can do the following to ensure that no duplicates are created:

```
var dataSchema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: Number,
    index: {
      unique: true
    }
  },
  name: String
},
{ _id: false });
```

Comment: [Error: document must have an _id before saving]